# How does routing for ASP.NET Web Pages work without global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-webpages

Web server with ASP.Net 4.0 installed, Web Pages 2.0 DLLs bin deployed.  Pages written in cshtml/razor, but routing is not working.

What is required on the server to activate routing when using only Web Pages as opposed to full MVC (where I'd have my routes defined in global.asax)?

Right now I can only call my pages using the traditional URL and query string.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: did you include "System.Web.Mvc.dll" and "System.Web.Routing.dll" in bin folder?

Comment: Had the MVC one. Just add routing but that and makes no difference. I assume that would be in the GAC on the server anyway.

Comment: which version of IIS you are using?

Comment: I guess you must need to change the pool of the website. **"ASP.Net v4.0 with integrated mode"**

Comment: As far as I know it is but will check with web admin tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of "routing" available in the Web Pages framework. The default routing works on matching URLs to file paths. It is quite flexible in that it allows for additional URL segments that populate a `UrlData` dictionary, and can enable some nice SEO-friendly URL construction. I have written about that here: [WebMatrix - URLs, UrlData and Routing for SEO](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/165/WebMatrix-URLs-UrlData-and-Routing-for-SEO).

The second kind of routing, which is similar to the routing available in MVC requires a package to be installed: [Routing For Web Pages](http://nuget.org/packages/WebPageRouteHandler). Once you have installed this, you can either populate your `RouteCollection` in an _AppStart.cshtml file (which you need to create yourself) or you can do so in `Application_Start` in global.asax. You can add a global.asax file by selecting the All option in the Choose A File Type dialog when you choose to add a file.

If you want to know how to use the Routing package, I have written about that too: [More Flexible Routing For ASP.NET Web Pages](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/187/More-Flexible-Routing-For-ASP.NET-Web-Pages)

Answer (score 3):

**Web Forms application**

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
        "~/categoriespage.aspx");
}
```

**MVC application**

**Global.asax**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

For more information :

[**How to: Use Routing with Web Forms**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx)

[**ASP.NET Routing not working on IIS 7.0**](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Mar/27/ASPNET-Routing-not-working-on-IIS-70)

[**Deploying ASP.NET MVC 3 to IIS 6**](http://www.codefrenzy.net/2011/10/19/deploying-asp-net-mvc-3-to-iis-6/)

[**IIS URL Rewriting and ASP.NET Routing**](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing)

[**ASP.NET Routing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: There is no global.asax in a simple web pages app. That is why I'm trying to find out what might be missing. Thanks though.

Comment: @Graeme I have added some links check that.