# Ignore first segment of url for globalization

Tags: c#, url, globalization

I was required to change the way the globalisation works on my project.

Today I have

- www.mysite.com.br
- www.mysite.com.mx
- www.mysite.com.ar

So I could access my pages like: `www.mysite.com.br/default.aspx`

and based on this, I make my way changing the language and the content, based on the URL

```
Country obj = dataContext.Country.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Domain.Equals(HttpContext.Current.Request.URL.Host.ToLower()));
```

But now, they said that they need it to be like this

- www.mysite.com/br
- www.mysite.com/mx
- www.mysite.com/ar

So I need to access my pages like: `www.mysite.com/br/default.aspx`

I could get the Country on my function by using this

```
Country obj = dataContext.Country.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Abbreviation.Equals(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments.Where(s => s != "/").First()));
```

But when I access `www.mysite.com/br/Default.aspx` he gives me the error "Server Error in '/' Application **The resource cannot be found**". Of course, I don't have a `Default.aspx` inside a folder named `br`.

I was reading about routes. But so far I couldn't implement those and I'm not sure if this is the right path for me atm

---

By routes, I'm trying something like this:

Global.asax ( I had to create one, because my project didn't have one )

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{lang}/Default.aspx",
        "~/Default.aspx"
    );
}
```

But the error is the same.

Comment: Can you rely on users entering the site on the "Default.aspx" page, or could they arrive on any page under the language specific subdirectory?

Comment: @Culme those pages with globalisation are public. The idea is that the person can move freely on the site From `Default.aspx` to `Contact.aspx` without any trouble. The language is set to change the content and the site-text messages.

Comment: I'm assuming this is MVC?

Comment: No, it isn't. The solution is a WebSite (it's not even a project) and without any framework (not even .Net) being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.

As it is a WebSite not a Project, I had to add `RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` inside `Application_Start` with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13937098/662581)